# Priority with transaction queues (msmq)

Tags: wcf, msmq

I need to support priority and my msmq is transnational. I am currently using WCF to send and receive messages. I just found out that this is not supported with the current implementation of msmq (version 4). Still, I need to support this.

I don't want to have multiple queues based on priority because at the end, the different queues are not connected. Also, its messy.

I was wondering if anything did a better solution to this problem?

What about putting a non-transaction queue in front of the transaction queue? messages will send with priority to the non-transaction queue, and when processed they will be sent to the transaction queue for the real processing...

Comment: If you put a non-transactional queue "in front" of a transactional queue you might as well just turn transactions off altogether.

Comment: Ok.  So what's the best way to get priority support?

Comment: See answer below - not sure why you're getting voted down either...

Answer (score 1):

Well, like you said, because transactions guarantee deliver of messages in order they were sent you can't prioritize them.

The only way I could think of doing this is to either create a new service contract and endpoint for high/low priority messages within the same service (not nice), or host two instances of your service, one for high and one for low priority.